# Thymeleaf: include js file and wrap to <![CDATA block

Tags: thymeleaf

Thymeleaf: how to include javascript file (
contents of this file) and wrap content this file with CDATA block
My js file is like this:

```
this is javascript file and have &&, I cannot edit this file
```

In my thymeleaf template I have:

```
<script th:include="http://address-to-file/myfile.js"></script>
```

I want to include this file, but I have error:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.

How i can wrap this include file to CDATA block? In my template I achieve this result:

```
/*<![CDATA[*/    
this is javascript file and have &&, I cannot edit this file
/*]]>*/
```

Comment: th:include to add external content to the page. this should work if you use th:src instead th:include

Comment: Thank you for your answer, replace th:include to th:src unfortunately it did not work, error occurs when parsing

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "http://address-to-file/myfile.js" (template:7)

Comment: I had the exact same problem, see my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51649880/2590616, that should fit your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **th:src** like this:

```
<script th:src="@{//address-to-your-file/yourfile.js";}"></script>
```

…which will render unmodified (except for URL rewriting), like:

```
<script src="address-to-your-file/yourfile.js"></script>
```