# thymeleaf - script and th:block

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

)
Is there any way to use "th:block" tag inside "script" tag? something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <th:block>
        var test = 1;
    </th:block>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the requirements to insert an external javascript (with thymleaf variables inside) and wrap it in cdata, it's based on @Pau's solution:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
  /*<![CDATA[*/
  /*[+ [# th:insert="~{path/to/file.js}" /] +]*/
  /*]]>*/
</script>
```

In these five lines we packed:

- Javascript inlining, to trigger thymeleaf parsing of the content (https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-inlining)
- Multiline comment CDATA notation, so that minimized code without linewraps will not be parsed as a comment only (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#Use_of_CDATA_in_program_output)
- Textual prototype-only comment blocks adding code, to prevent rendering the content in static files and prevent the IDE from being confused by invalid code. (https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#textual-prototype-only-comment-blocks-adding-code)
- Natural javascript templates, to use thymeleaf inside javascript, we used the empty tag approach and we omit th:block here, because it is the default (https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#natural-javascript-and-css-templates)
- Inserting of fragments with th:insert to insert a transpiled/minified external javascript with thymeleaf variables included. You can use th:text or th:utext too, but these insert the content of the external javascript without parsing it, so in our case the variables wouldn't have been resolved. (https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html)
- Finally the fragment specific syntax, to include a template via template path (https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#fragment-specification-syntax)

Answer (score 5):

You should use the attribute `th:inline="javascript"`, then you can use a `th:block` but not in a tag, you must use a syntax like next:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    [#th:block th:each="item : ${items}"]
      - [#th:block th:utext="${item}" /]
    [/th:block]
</script>
```