# How to use Custom AbstractElementTagProcessor inside <script> tag

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

My custom tag works outside `<script>` tag but not inside it.

Here is my sample code

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    function init() {
        var text = <customtag:write text="Hello World"/>;
    }
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

the expected output should be `var text = "Hello World";` inside `init()` function but it just prints exactly `var text = <customtag:write text="Hello World"/>;`.

I know I can use `/*[[${'Hello World'}]]*/ "";` so don't give me that answer pls. I'm currently trying to migrate an old system that uses struts 1 with jsp and it has custom tags that can be use inside `<script>` tag.

Comment: is this you are looing for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43674862/thymeleaf-script-and-thblock

Comment: @ProGu it's not.